# Lag spikes on my website

Tags: server, webserver, vps

I have a heavy traffic site that gets about +200 concurrent users and receives 4k+ uniques daily. My site seems to load slow for a few minutes and then fast for a few minutes and the pattern continues on.

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32bit. It uses nginx as the webserver and php-fpm. I also have APC installed. My site uses Wordpress with caching plugin.

This is what my top looks like
http://pastebin.com/JDULwAxm

This is nginx conf
http://pastebin.com/GXHTw9dG

This is php-fpm conf
http://pastebin.com/NWznCs3r

This is mysql conf
http://pastebin.com/sXRT7Jf9

Can anyone help me optimize to make the site stable? If you think my configurations are alright then do you think it's the host's side that is at fault for the instability?

Comment: can this be moved?

Comment: Flag was noted but mod declined to move

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me. May be it is a problem of "slow questions". That is, questions to the database that imply searching or filtering by unindexed fields, huge joins or something like that.

May be you need to optimize your database design. In my case, after some minor changes, my Intel Atom based server has passed from a load of about 0.9 to a load of about 0.1 (serving 20k ~ 25k pages a day).